# Window.open doesn't work when original window size is specified

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, resize, window

I have a script that opens a chrome window like so `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\" --window-size=1280,118 --window-position=0,0 --app="file:///C:/desktop/test.html"` I need to open another smaller popup window from that window but the popup always opens in the same size as its parent (1280x118). I have tested using window.open('','','resizeable, width=100,height=200') from a regular chrome window and it works as expected. It seems that window.open does not respect the width and height specified if it is launched from a window with a specified window-size. Are there any alternatives to window.open? Or does anybody know how to make this work in Chrome? Its working fine in IE but want to phase out IE for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by setting window.open to a variable and then using window.resizeTo to change its size.

````
            var myWindow=window.open('','newWin','width=200,height=100');
            myWindow.resizeTo(200,300);
            myWindow.moveTo(500, 100);
            myWindow.focus(); ```
````